# mysqlでleft joinした後にid is null としたとき、join の条件が消えてしまう

Tags: mysql

テーブルA, B, Cがあり、特定のCに関連するAを求めたい。

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a
  INNER JOIN B b
    ON b.id = a.b_id
  LEFT JOIN C c
    ON c.b_id = b.id AND c.type = 'hogehoge'
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

このとき、 `c.type = 'hogehoge'` 以外の type も抽出されてしまいます。

Answer (score 3):

`type = 'hogehoge'`のレコードのみを抽出したいのであれば、`c.type = 'hogehoge'`を結合条件ではなく抽出条件にしましょう。

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a
  INNER JOIN B b
    ON b.id = a.b_id
  LEFT JOIN C c
    ON c.b_id = b.id
WHERE c.type = 'hogehoge'
```